# PHP syntax - assign assoc value to an array

Tags: php

Apparently this code does not work. The problem is described as:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_DOUBLE_ARROW

My code:

```
if(isset($_POST['my_custom_contact'])) {
    $registration_data[] = 'custom_contact' => $_POST['my_custom_contact'];
}
```

How should I rewrite that associative bit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on what you want to do (I haven't understand it), it can be this:

```
$registration_data[] = array('custom_contact' => $_POST['my_custom_contact']);
```

or

```
$registration_data['custom_contact'] = $_POST['my_custom_contact'];
```

Comment: @Zanathel too easy, I suppose :)

Comment: I guess my question is, with the name=>value pair, if the name 'custom_contact' does not already appear in the array, will the above methods create it and then assign the $_POST value to it?

Answer (score 2):

You assign it as you usually do. You only use the `=>` notation when initialising an associative array.

```
$registration_data['custom_contact'] = $_POST['my_custom_contact'];
```

and...

```
$registration_data = array ('custom_contact' => $_POST['my_custom_contact']);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to write it like:

```
$registration_data[] = array('custom_contact' => $_POST['my_custom_contact']);
```